# Unable to load js script in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I try to reach the two custom scripts in js from my custom Wordpress theme. 
I got the following code in `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
   wp_register_script('html2Canvas',get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/html2canvas.js', array('jquery'),true);
   wp_register_script('CustomController',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/CustomController.js', array('jquery','html2canvas'),true);
   wp_enqueue_script('html2Canvas');
   wp_enqueue_script('CustomController');
}
```

An the followin folder structure

```
<theme_folder>
 |- functions.php
 |-js
   |- html2canvas.js
   |- CustomController.js 
 |[...]
```

Comment: An errors appearing in the browser console?

Comment: No error on console or dockers logs

Comment: What about in the WordPress debug.log file?  Have you enabled WP_DEBUG ?

Comment: have you written wp_footer() in footer.php ?

Comment: Yes good point @Tristup, without wp_footer() the scripts won't be output in the footer as coded.

Comment: That its, i put wp_footer() and now works.

Comment: Great it works for you

Comment: Well done @Tristup :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AndrewSchultz